# Code snippets in PhpStorm on sidebar

Tags: phpstorm, sidebar, code-snippets

It is possible to use code snippets in PHPStorm from sidebar, something like in Komodo IDE/Edit?
I can double click on snippet name and it's content is added to file.

Komodo Edit Toolbox - screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxvYO.jpg

Comment: There is no such functionality in PhpStorm, maybe via some custom plugin. But in general -- why do you actually need it? You do not remember your snippets (Live Templates in PhpStorm)? If so -- `Ctrl+J` (using Default keymap) will show you list of templates in standard code completion popup.

Comment: Yes, I don't remember them. I've been using such functionality in komodo for many years. For me it's quicker to access snippets like that. Well then, I'll have to get used to CTRL+J.

Comment: BTW -- do you know what Emmet is? Have you used it? PhpStorm supports it (tag expansion) so you can use it in appropriate context (HTML/XML and alike (e.g. Smarty/Twig templates)) with no need for snippets/live templates for most cases (e.g. your screenshot -- no need for snippet for pair of `article` tags .. just `article[TAB]` and done).